# Exclude a group from regex

Tags: regex

I need regex results coming from docker commands.

For case 1: `docker1: mycompany.com:5000/example_1:0.0.2`
I should obtain 3 groups :

1. group 1: **docker1**
2. group 2: **example_1**
3. group 3: **0.0.2**

For case 2 : `docker2: mycompany.com:5000/example_2` i should obtain 2 groups

1. group 1: **docker2**
2. group 2: **example_2**

For case 3: `docker3: mycompany.com:5000/example_3:latest` i should get 3 groups like the first one

1. group 1: **docker3**
2. group 2: **example_3**
3. group 3: **latest**

I am using the following regex to do so :

```
^(.*): mycompany\.com:5000\/((\S*)\:(\w+.?\w+.?\w+)|\S*)$
```

but it seems I can't remove the second group on the 1st and 3rd case

Please find in the [following](https://regex101.com/r/Qo54Tb/1) link what I did.

May please someone guide me on how to remove group2 ( example_1:0.0.2 or example_3:latest)?

Comment: Simply make it a non-capturing group ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qo54Tb/2)).

Comment: Oh i forgot this.  Thank you so much for your help. I have so much to learn on this topic ! It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You could write the pattern using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) and note to escape the dot to match it literally.

```
^([^\n:]*): mycompany\.com:5000\/([^\s:]+)(?::(\d+(?:\.\d+)*|\w+))?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `([^\n:]*)` Capture **group 1**, match any char except `:` or a newline
- `: mycompany\.com:5000\/` Match `: mycompany.com:5000/`
- `([^\s:]+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ times a non whitespace char excluding `:`
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `:` Match literally
  - `(` Capture **group 3**

    - `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` Match 1+ digits and optionally repeat `.` and again 1+ digits
    - `|` Or
    - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
  - `)` Close group
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vfohsk/1)

Or a bit shorter:

```
^([^\n:]*): mycompany\.com:5000\/([^\s:]+)(?::([^\s:]+))?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/isrN56/1)